# Android - Save image listener

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to save the picture on the device. I will change the activity when the image is saved. How do I know when a picture is saved?

**Save image code:**

```
 public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        File file = null;
                        try {
                            file = createImageFile();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
                            ostream.flush();
                            ostream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e("IOException", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
```

Comment: do you know `Observer` pattern?

Comment: After `ostream.close()` the picture is saved. You can remove the createImageFile() statement as the file will be created by the new FileOutputStream. But if file==null you will have a NullPointerException of course. So decide wich path you will take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving the image in Gallery will save the image on your device eventually.
Try below code :

`MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourBitmap, yourTitle , yourDescription);`

```
public class CapturePhotoUtils {

    /**
     * A copy of the Android internals  insertImage method, this method populates the 
     * meta data with DATE_ADDED and DATE_TAKEN. This fixes a common problem where media 
     * that is inserted manually gets saved at the end of the gallery (because date is not populated).
     * @see android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media#insertImage(ContentResolver, Bitmap, String, String)
     */
    public static final String insertImage(ContentResolver cr, 
            Bitmap source, 
            String title, 
            String description) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, title);
        values.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, title);
        values.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, description);
        values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        // Add the date meta data to ensure the image is added at the front of the gallery
        values.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());

        Uri url = null;
        String stringUrl = null;    /* value to be returned */

        try {
            url = cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

            if (source != null) {
                OutputStream imageOut = cr.openOutputStream(url);
                try {
                    source.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, imageOut);
                } finally {
                    imageOut.close();
                }

                long id = ContentUris.parseId(url);
                // Wait until MINI_KIND thumbnail is generated.
                Bitmap miniThumb = Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, id, Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
                // This is for backward compatibility.
                storeThumbnail(cr, miniThumb, id, 50F, 50F,Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
            } else {
                cr.delete(url, null, null);
                url = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (url != null) {
                cr.delete(url, null, null);
                url = null;
            }
        }

        if (url != null) {
            stringUrl = url.toString();
        }

        return stringUrl;
    }

    /**
     * A copy of the Android internals StoreThumbnail method, it used with the insertImage to
     * populate the android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media#insertImage with all the correct
     * meta data. The StoreThumbnail method is private so it must be duplicated here.
     * @see android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media (StoreThumbnail private method)
     */
    private static final Bitmap storeThumbnail(
            ContentResolver cr,
            Bitmap source,
            long id,
            float width, 
            float height,
            int kind) {

        // create the matrix to scale it
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        float scaleX = width / source.getWidth();
        float scaleY = height / source.getHeight();

        matrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY);

        Bitmap thumb = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0,
            source.getWidth(),
            source.getHeight(), matrix,
            true
        );

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
        values.put(Images.Thumbnails.KIND,kind);
        values.put(Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID,(int)id);
        values.put(Images.Thumbnails.HEIGHT,thumb.getHeight());
        values.put(Images.Thumbnails.WIDTH,thumb.getWidth());

        Uri url = cr.insert(Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        try {
            OutputStream thumbOut = cr.openOutputStream(url);
            thumb.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, thumbOut);
            thumbOut.close();
            return thumb;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            return null;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

To know if image is saved or not just put a check in storeThumbnail method.
Hope this answers your question.

Comment: `Saving the image in Gallery will  ...` You mean: `Saving the image in/by MediaStore will ...`?

Comment: @blackapps yes you're right. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what do intend to do but you can always save the image and then call the activity at the end of the function

Another way if using fileObserver : [FileObserver examples](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.os.FileObserver)